# Change a name field from LAST FIRST ordered to FIRST LAST ordered

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an excel spreadsheet with about 700 entries.  The names are listed as "DOE JOHN" (no comma separating the names).  I need to format them so they read JOHN DOE.

1.) I would like to learn how to do this in excel.

2.) I would like to learn how to do this in linux.

Thanks!

Comment: What will you do when there are first and/or last names with spaces in between?  E.g. Mary Jo Smith, John Doe Williams.

Comment: Are any of the names compound? If so, how is that indicated? DOE JOHN is easy, what about GEORGE ROBERT JOHN?  Is that Robert John George or John George Robert?

Comment: There are middle initials on some of them.  I forgot to mention that!

It looks like the names are formatted Last First Middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your LAST FIRST data in A1:A10, for example, paste this worksheet formula into B1.  Then copy and paste into B2:B10.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))&" "&LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

If you then want to get rid of the LAST FIRST data, select B1:B10 and choose Edit - Copy.  Select A1:A10, select Edit - Paste Special - Values.

Be sure to review B1:B10 before you paste values over your original data to make sure it worked like you expect.

Comment: Sorry tyebud, I edited the answer to show how to use it. It's a worksheet formula that you paste into a cell.

Comment: Dick,

That you very much for your response.

I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Dick,

I've entered the formula, and it is outputting the name in the same order.  Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, I put the wrong formula in there.  I've fixed it. Try it now.